# How to store every video duration and url in separate local storage variable? (Vimeo,Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

Basically i'm trying to store the video url and duration in localstorage but i want to do it for any video
it is working for only one i don't care how many just the localstorage save every video url and duration separate?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


let prev_url= localStorage.getItem('videourl');


player.getDuration().then(function(duration) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
    jQuery('#total_minutes').html('<i class="fal fa-clock"></i>'+minutes+' minutes');
});

jQuery('.video_trailer_embed').each(function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        if(href==prev_url || prev_url==null) {
        localStorage.setItem('videourl', href);
        let time = localStorage.getItem('videoProgress');
        player.setCurrentTime(time);
        }
        function run_url_every_2seconds(){
            localStorage.setItem('videourl', href);
            console.log(href);
        } 
        player.on('play', function() {  
            setInterval(run_url_every_2seconds,2000);
        });
});




/*player.on('pause', function() {
    player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
        localStorage.setItem('videoProgress', seconds);

    }); 
}); */


function run_every_2seconds(){
        player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
        localStorage.setItem('videoProgress', seconds);

        });
} 
player.on('play', function() {  
setInterval(run_every_2seconds,2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index `i` to each localStorage key to make the names different on each page. And add `window.location.pathname` to differentiate between pages. Otherwise, you're overwriting the same value in storage each time.

```
jQuery('.video_trailer_embed').each(function(i){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        if(href==prev_url || prev_url==null) {
            localStorage.setItem('videourl' + window.location.pathname + i, href);
            let time = localStorage.getItem('videoProgress' + window.location.pathname + i);
            player.setCurrentTime(time);
        }
        function run_url_every_2seconds(){
            localStorage.setItem('videourl' + window.location.pathname + i, href);
            console.log(href);
        } 
        player.on('play', function() {  
            setInterval(run_url_every_2seconds,2000);
        });
});
```

Comment: it is still overwriting because i value is not changing

Comment: i is changing. are you applying the video_trailer_embed class to every element?

Comment: video_trailer_embed is apply to every iframe of video but they are on different pages.one video in one page

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for accepting the answer. Upvotes help too if you have the time :) Cheers.